# Cannot connect local PostgreSQL DB in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, express, node-postgres

I connect my `PostgreSQL` local database in Node.js server using `pg`.

All worked fine, but suddenly it stopped to work.

This is my code:

```
const {Pool} = require('pg')
const connectionString = process.env.DATABASE_URL;
const ssl = process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production' ? '?ssl=true' : '';
const pool = new Pool({
    connectionString: connectionString + ssl
});

const db = {
    pool: pool,
    test: async () => {
        try {
            console.log('before connection');
            let result = await pool.query('SELECT $1::text as status', ['connected']);
            console.log('connected')
            return result.rows[0].status;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
            return null;
        }
    }
}

module.exports = db;
```

Here I call it:

```
const express = require('express')
const Router = express.Router();
const db = require('./database')

Router.get('/testdb', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let result = await db.test();
        res.status(200).send(result);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error);
    }
})
```

It stuck on `pool.query`. 'before connection' is logged, no error is thrown.

The very same code works fine with my remote db, and I can connect the local db with pgAdmin.

Answer (score 2):

This was an incompatibility issue between `pg` and the node.js 14 version. See also the following GitHub issues where this was tracked and fixed:

- https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2180
- Pull request: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/pull/2171

tl;dr: Upgrade `pg` to a version larger than 8.0.3 (`pg>=8.0.3`).

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem in node version - some days ago I updated it to `14.5.0`.

revise it to `12.18.2 LTS` solve the problem.